# How do I get a Bluetooth headset working with my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop?

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth headset. I've used it with my (Android) phone, but I'd like to get it working with my desktop that's running Ubuntu 16.04. I have a USB Bluetooth dongle plugged in, which `lsusb` sees:

```
$ lsusb | grep Blue
Bus 005 Device 010: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
```

How do I get it to pair and connect to my headphones? How do I set the headphones as the default audio device when connected?

I tried running `blueman-manager`, which pops up the following dialog:

[image: Connection to BlueZ failed ; Bluez daemon is not running, blueman-manager cannot continue. This probably means that there were no Bluetooth adapters detected or Bluetooth daemon was not started.]

Looking for solutions to that error I tried:

- `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart`
- `sudo apt-get purge blueman bluez bluetooth; sudo apt-get install blueman  bluez bluetooth`
- `sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`
- `sudo hciconfig hci0 reset`
- `sudo -i pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover`

But none of these resolve the error. I'm not even sure if `blueman-manager` is useful/necessary to getting my headset working.

So how do I get my headset working?

Comment: Try with a 17.10 LiveUSB. My bluetooth in 16.04 was lousy, too...but newer releases of Ubuntu got better and better, and now it works wonderfully. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Good to know. I'm sticking to LTS releases, but I guess 18.04 is not far off now.